# UV Editing - how to quickly select another object

Tags: texturing, uv

I would like to quickly select another object and see its uv editing.

I know i can

1. change to object mode
2. select the other object
3. go to uv editing again
4. change to edit mode again

which are 4 clicks.

Is there any quicker way?

Comment: I thought Alt Q worked only in Sculpt mode, nice to see that it works in every modes   ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> to switch from an object to the other (works since the latest versions). Also works in *Texture Paint* mode, *Sculpt* mode...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In complement to moonboots answer, the possibility to change object is also indicated in the outliner.

When in UV editing (or other modes), the edited object is indicated by a mesh symbol and other objects compatible with this mode are indicated by a dot.

You can change the object or add one, clicking or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> clicking on this icon:

[image]

All is in the documentation [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/modes.html#switching-objects).

Comment: +1 works also perfect, but moonboots was a bit quicker ;)

Comment: yes he was and his answer should be accepted (of course) Chris